# "Topological" spaces without axioms

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is an ordered pair $(X,\tau)$ where $X$ is a set of points and $\tau$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, satisfying certain axioms (an arbitrary union of things in $\tau$ is in $\tau$, etc.). A continuous function from $(X,\tau_X)$ to $(Y,\tau_Y)$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ where the inverse images of things in $\tau_Y$ are in $\tau_X$. This creates the category Top.

What happens if we throw away the axioms, and just consider things of the form $(X,\tau)$ where $\tau$ is *any* collection of subsets of $X$? We can still define continuous functions the same way, so we still get a category, right? Is this category interesting? Do these spaces have a name?

Comment: Sierpinski's [**General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486411486) book starts out with what he calls "Frechet $V$spaces" in which for each point there is an arbitrarily specified collection of subsets associated with that point (the *neighborhoods* of that point). Off-hand, I don't know whether it is required that the point belong to all of its neighborhoods, but even if so, this is fairly general. He manages to define a lot of topological-like notions and prove some basic results even in this full generality (this being in the first few pages of his book).